# Tutorials / Samples of Laravel CREATE and UPDATE forms that include select boxes

Tags: php, forms, laravel, drop-down-menu

Working on a project that has several data tables that get updated via forms. I have had no issues until I needed a drop down list that draws its values from a data set.

Does anyone know of any tutorials or samples that explains how to best accomplish this?

I have read up on Eloquent `lists()` but am still just not grasping it.

I can create the form to add a NEW record, I just have NO idea how to do an update form that uses the current data set value to set the `SELECTED` value in the drop down list

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lists` method now returns an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` so you'll need to call `all()` to get an array.

```
$corpcats = OpCategories::where('corp','=','1')->lists('name', 'id')->all();

$corpcats = ['Make a selection'] + $corpcats;
```

It's documented in the [upgrade guide to Laravel 5.1.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0) under the heading *The `lists` Method*

> The `lists` method now returns a `Collection` instance instead of a plain array for Eloquent queries. If you would like to convert the `Collection` into a plain array, use the `all` method:
>
> `User::lists('id')->all();`
>
> Be aware that the Query Builder `lists` method still returns an array.

---

**Update after OP edited the question.**

In order to repopulate a form you can use the `old()` helper which simply calls the method `Input::old()`.

Controller

```
$idToSelectOnFirstLoad = 1; // Perhaps selected from database or in a Model

$items = Model::lists('name', 'id');

$items = ['Select'] + $items;

return view('viewname', compact('idToSelectOnFirstLoad', 'items'));
```

View

```
{!! Form::select('fieldname', $items, old('fieldname', $idToSelectOnFirstLoad)); !}}
```

What this does is it

- creates a select list with `$items`
- looks to see if there's a previously submit form value using `old()`
- if there's not a previously selected value, the second parameter of `old()` then kicks in and it selects the one you put in `$idToSelectOnFirstLoad`.
- if you leave `$idToSelectOnFirstLoad` as null or 0 the `Select` will be auto selected

Comment: Thanks, I found that buried in the documentation and adjusted code.  Worked great.

Comment: Just seen you've edited your question and now it's fairly different and the answer is less relevant. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That is excactly what I needed.